# What module handles links of the form <a href="internal:archive">?

Tags: 7

I'm maintaining a website with drupal 6 and recently did an update. I have some links of the following form:

```
<a href="internal:forum"> … </a>
<a href="internal:archive"> … </a>
<a href="internal:album/2014"> … </a>
```

Since the update, every link of that form is dead (since the navigator just tries to open the url "`internal:forum`", which is completely invalid as is)

It may be a module I forgot to enable again after the update, but I have too much of them to test them one by one, and none of them seems related to that sort of link at all.

What are those links? What is handling them and what do I need to make them work again?

Comment: Are those links in node content? If so it's probably a module that provides a text filter

Comment: Yes it is, I'll have another look at my module list and see if something seems related to text filtering or substitution.

Comment: Found it, the module's name was "Path filter", thanks! I'll post and accept an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Clive suggested in the comments, I was searching for a module involving links when I should have searched for some kind of text filtering.

I've found the responsible module : [Path Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathfilter), and I indeed forgot to enable it again after the update.

The `internal:forum` pattern is written in a node's content, and is changed to a valid path in the final page.